# How to sort numbers in php?

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort numbers from 1 to 10 on names and from 19 to 10 on surnames for 10 times. Im expecting this:

```
name 1 surname 19
name 2 surname 18
name 3 surname 17
name 4 surname 16
name 5 surname 15
name 6 surname 14
name 7 surname 13
name 8 surname 12
name 9 surname 11
name 10 surname 10
```

Im using rand function but its giving me random numbers like:

```
name 5 surname 19
name 9 surname 15
name 4 surname 11
name 2 surname 12
name 1 surname 16
```

Any help? Here is my code its OOP:

```
class people {
      private $name, $surname;

      function __construct() {
          $this->name=rand(1,10);
          $this->surname=rand(10,19);
          echo " Name = ".$this->name." "."Surname = ".$this->surname."<br>";
      }
  }

  for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    $z[$i]= new people($i);
```

Comment: So don't use random numbers, no?

Comment: Seems, you want `range` instead of rand

Comment: yes, I dont want to use random numbers. I need them just like in example above

Comment: I tried ```range``` but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why no so? You already set a param to the constructor

```
  function __construct($i) {
      $this->name = $i;
      $this->surname = 20-$i;
      echo " Name = ".$this->name." "."Surname = ".$this->surname."<br>";
  }
```